# Why write an EVM in bytecode, and not in something like Python or Go?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, cpp-ethereum, bytecode

I know that Ethereum runs in virtual byte code and there's a javascript-like wrapper language called Solidity. This question is about **why** the developers chose this approach?

What makes it infeasible to write a smart contract blockchain in pure Python or Javascript? What are the advantages of doing it Ethereum's way?

Why did Ethereum choose to write its blockchain on EVM? Why is the EVM so limited, and how does it look under the hood?

Comment: i think this may inswer your question even if it is about Java https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/142/what-was-the-reason-to-invent-the-evm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the merit of creating new smart contract languages like Solidity instead of using other languages?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3112/what-is-the-merit-of-creating-new-smart-contract-languages-like-solidity-instead)

Comment: It is definitely not a duplicate of that question. ^

Comment: This low-level stuff is more what I was inquiring on https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Development-Tutorial plus the first comment here and "third interpretation" below is a good answer and possible duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the EVM does have some flaws (for example, not being able to poll sites outside the blockchain), it is a fine piece of engineering in that it can accurately tabulate memory usage in form of decreasing gas, is extremely efficient in how it uses memory (although it still cant really do much), and most importantly, it is entirely deterministic (meaning its execution is consistent regardless of time, space, or hardware). It never messes up and causes a blockchain fork, and so far, it hasnt caused any major security holes.

Using another language would likely mean that you wouldnt be able to do stuff that you could normally do in said language. You'd basically be forced to always change your usual approach when coding in that language because packages and other stuff wouldn't be compatible with a low-memory, deterministic coding environment.

I really like the low-level analysis from 2015 written in my question's comment section. Check it out if you have time.

Answer (score 1):

> What makes it infeasible to write a smart contract blockchain in pure
>   Python or Javascript?

**First interpretation of the question: smart contracts**

Nothing. You can write a smart contract in any language you like, as long as it compiles to the EVM bytecode. But to do that, you'd need to also write a compiler that created the said bytecode.

The currently available languages, and therefore compilers, are detailed here: [What are the contract languages?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-are-the-contract-languages/368#368)

For some details on why, for example, a language like Golang couldn't be used natively, see here: [What is the merit of creating new smart contract languages like Solidity instead of using other languages?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3112/what-is-the-merit-of-creating-new-smart-contract-languages-like-solidity-instead)

This would be a good starting point in putting together arguments as to why certain other languages couldn't be used natively.

**Edit: Second interpretation of the question: client**

There are multiple implementations of the client.

- Geth: golang
- Parity: Rust
- [Pythereum](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum): Python
- [ethereumj](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj): Java
- Heskell? Deprecated?
- Probably others?

**Third interpretation of the question: Why an EVM and not something else?**

This is probably answered in this previous thread: [What was the reason to invent the EVM?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/142/what-was-the-reason-to-invent-the-evm/9323#9323)

Comment: You didnt answer my question. I'm not trying to compile a smart contract for Ethereum. Ethereum != smart contracts

Comment: Okay, do you mean the important word here is "blockchain" rather than "smart contract"?

Comment: Yes. That is correct

Answer (score 0):

> I know that Ethereum runs in virtual byte code and there's a javascript-like wrapper language called Solidity. This question is about why the developers chose this approach?

I'm not the developers, so I can't say exactly why. They did try to document some of this though in their [rationale](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale#virtual-machine) document

> What makes it infeasible to write a smart contract blockchain in pure Python or Javascript? What are the advantages of doing it Ethereum's way?

If properly sandboxed there is no reason Python or Javascript could not be used. However, the complexities of garbage collection and assigning a gas cost to every operation is a clear hurdle to overcome. I work on a separate project that integrates the EVM into a separate blockchain and I recently did some prototyping so that smart contracts could be [written in C](https://gist.github.com/Earlz/87dd041d44f5f160ebedaa1427f9f2fa) (x86 VM). It produced very efficient and compact bytecode, but C is definitely not the language you would want to write a smart contract in due to it's memory safety issues and various pitfalls.

> Why did Ethereum choose to write its blockchain on EVM? Why is the EVM so limited, and how does it look under the hood?

The EVM was designed to be very simplistic and consistent in it's set of available opcodes. As such, almost every opcode works on 256-bit integers. This extends even to the available memory address space. However, using anything beyond maybe 20 bits of memory address space would most likely exceed the block gas limit due to the memory architecture used. Contract memory space can't have gaps, so if you try to write to address 0xFFFF, it will actually charge you for 64Kbytes of memory, even if you only intended to write a single byte. Along with this, the storage model used for persistence of data is also 256-bit based. It is effectively a key-value space where the key (address) is 256-bits wide, and the value is also 256-bits. Although the EVM has access to memory etc, it is primarily a stack based machine, where each word in the stack is 256-bits. So each opcode takes a series of arguments from the stack, rather than registers or directly specifying memory as in some VMs and CPU architectures.

This consistency and simplicity of the EVM allows a gas model to be made without a great amount of effort, and allows for the EVM's behavior to be more easily audited and implemented.

Comment: What is "garbage collection"?

Comment: @koampapapa a piece of code that basically works behind the scenes to manage memory, ensuring you can always allocate memory, and when you stop using the memory it detects that it can no longer be accessed and frees it and/or makes it available for reuse. Such a concept is not compatible with the EVM though because there is no way to free memory, though the potential for reuse would save in gas costs, though probably would not be worth it as the garbage collector would spend more gas in execution time than saved in memory costs